# Import Semantic-ui css without the classes being scoped locally || Semantic-ui to use classes that are being scoped locally

Tags: reactjs, postcss, semantic-ui-react, rollupjs, semantic-ui-css

I want to selectively use `semantic-ui-css` classes in my components. The problem is that I use PostCSS modules option which scopes locally all the class names for a specific component. When I use `semantic-ui-react` components, for example a button, it renders element `button` with classes `ui button`, but the included css gets scoped locally so instead of `button` i get `button-min_ui__14RRq`

I need to do one of two things:

1. Import Semantic-ui css without the classes being scoped locally
2. Make Semantic-ui components to use classes that are being scoped locally

For now I see that I have only one option:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import semantic from 'semantic-ui-css/components/button.min.css'

export default class Test extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
        <Button className={[semantic.ui, semantic.button]}>Click Here</Button>
      )
  }
}
```

I'm explicitly stating what classes the button is to use. It works, but I have  to do that for every element and it keeps the default classes. So I get `ui button button-min_ui__14RRq button-min_button__Uio9b`

Is there a way of doing this without it keeping the default classes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but will give it a shot. Should you try excluding the semantic/global styles from PostCSS?
eg. If you are using webpack use 'exclude' in the loader definition.
(it's something we do in one of our the projects where I work)

Laura

Answer (score 0):

you are having similar problem to me.

[Making External Library(Semantic ui React) and CSS module work with webpack css-loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57241286/making-external-librarysemantic-ui-react-and-css-module-work-with-webpack-css)

From my understanding,you want to exclude semantic-ui-react-library styling from css module so that it work with your application. You can create multiple rules for css loader to resolve this.

Take a look at this [Using Semantic UI With CSS Modules in Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49136024/using-semantic-ui-with-css-modules-in-webpack/50556115#50556115)

Answer (score 0):

I always use `css` of a library not the components they provide, I write my own.

So install only `semantic-ui-css`. Now import like below in your react application.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```